# Canon FD lens mount adapter for Olympus Pen E-PL1

Tags: lens, canon, olympus, micro-four-thirds

First time poster in this forum, and I want to ask this before I spend money.

My parents were avid photographers, and both had Canon AE-1 Cameras.  I have an Olympus Pen E-PL1.

I have a few lenses from my parents.  Two of them are FD lenses.

I also know that my Olympus camera is a Micro 4/3rds lens mount.

Will [this Lens Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003EAVUMK) work with the Canon lenses I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will this Lens Mount work with the Canon lenses I have?

YES, It will allow you to mount your FD, or FL, lens's to your PEN E-PL1 but see note below,  I can not speak to functionality as I know nothing about the PEN E-PL1.

From the amazon link.

> Note: This is a manual adapter, so lens functions that rely on
> electronic communication with the camera body (autofocus, AE metering,
> image stabilization, etc.) will be disrupted. Set your exposure
> manually or meter using your camera's Aperture Priority (stop-down)
> mode. If your lens does not have a manual aperture control ring, it
> will stop down to its smallest f/stop by default. All pictures are for
> illustration purposes only. Actual product may vary slightly due to
> ongoing improvements in design.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!

Comment: Note that the AF will likely be slow, likely much slower than a M.Zuiko MF3 lens.

Comment: Fd lenses are manual focus.  There is no AF.   FD lenses will work fine with a simple glassless adapter.   Use stop down metering techniques.  Don't expect to take quick pics either.